# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Tags: java, angular, spring

I'm trying update project and i'm facing with this problem "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"

Here's update-project.thml:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
...
</head>

<body ng-app="dateInputExample">
...


<div class="container custom-container">
  <form [formGroup]="updateProjectForm" (ngSubmit)="updateProject(updateProjectForm.value)" class="ui form"
        style="margin-left: 3%; width: 30%;">
    <h1 id="projectTitle">Update Project</h1>

    <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
      <div style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <div class="field">
          <label>Project Name</label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="projectName" class="form-control" name="projectName"
                 [(ngModel)]="projectData.name" placeholder="Your project name"
                 [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : submitted && updateProjectForm.controls.projectName.errors}"/>
          <div *ngIf="submitted && updateProjectForm.controls.projectName.errors" class="err_msg form-text">
            <p class="err-msg">Project Name is required</p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="field" style="margin-top: 5%;">
          <label>Project Description</label>
          <textarea rows="4" cols="50" formControlName="projectDescription" [(ngModel)]="projectData.description"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Your  project description"></textarea>
        </div>

        <label>Expiry Date</label>
        <div>
          <input type="date" formControlName="expiryDate" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="dateInForm"
                 placeholder="expiryDate"
                 min="2019-08-07" max="2020-12-31" required/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-panel ui-helper-hidden">
          <label>Budget</label>
          <input type="number" formControlName="budget" maxlength="16" placeholder="Budget"
                 [(ngModel)]="projectData.budget">
        </div>

        <div class="field" style="margin-top: 5%;" *ngIf="showSkills">
          <label>Skills</label>
          <div class="ui segment">
            <app-skills-multiselect>
            </app-skills-multiselect>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field" style="margin-top: 5%;" *ngIf="showProjectType">
          <label>Project Type</label>
          <div class="ui segment">
            <app-pt-multiselect></app-pt-multiselect>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field" style="margin-top: 5%;">
          <button type="submit" class="ui primary button">Update</button>
          <a routerLink="/back" class="ui button">Cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
...

</body>
</html>
```

Here's update-project.ts

```
...
export class UpdateProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private projectService: ProjectService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private rout: Router, private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.router = rout;
    this.updateProjectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      projectName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      ...
    });
  }
  saved = false;
  submitted: boolean;
  projectName: string;
  router: Router;
  project: Project;
  projectData: any = {};
  dateInForm: string;
  showMsg = false;
  showErrMsg = false;
  showSkills = false;
  showProjectType = false;
  skill = [];
  selectedType = [];

  @ViewChild(PrMultiselectComponent, { static: false })
  private prMultiselectComponent: PrMultiselectComponent;

  @ViewChild(SkillsMultiselectComponent, { static: false })
  private skillMultiselectComponent: SkillsMultiselectComponent;

  id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
  updateProjectForm: any;

  save() {
    this.saved = true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectService.getProjectById(this.id).subscribe(data => {
      this.projectData = data;
      console.log(this.projectData);

      // Show selected skills
      this.skillMultiselectComponent.selectedItems = this.projectData.skillSet.map(this.skillMultiselectComponent.parseSkillsList);
      console.log(this.skillMultiselectComponent);

      // Show selected Type
      this.selectedType.push({ id: this.projectData.projectType.id,
        itemName: this.projectData.projectType.name });
      this.prMultiselectComponent.selectedTypeItems = this.selectedType;

      // TODO don't show expiry date
      // this.dateInForm = this.datePipe.transform(this.projectData.expiryDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
      // console.log(this.dateInForm);


    });
    this.showSkills = true;
    this.showProjectType = true;
  }
  canDeactivate(): boolean | Observable<boolean> {

    if (!this.saved) {
      return confirm('Are yo sure you want to left this page without saving information?');
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  updateProject(projectDataFromForm) {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure, you want to update?')) {
      console.log('in updateProject()');
      console.log(projectDataFromForm);
      this.submitted = true;
      this.project.name = projectDataFromForm.projectName;
      this.project.description = projectDataFromForm.projectDescription;
      this.project.expiryDate = projectDataFromForm.expiryDate;
      this.project.budget = projectDataFromForm.budget;
      // this.project.projectTypeId = this.idprojecttype;
      this.project.projectTypeId = this.prMultiselectComponent.getSelectedItems();
      this.project.skills = this.skillMultiselectComponent.getSelectedItems();
      // var data = this.selectedItems.map(t=>t.id);


      this.projectService.updateProject(this.id, this.project).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.updateProjectForm.reset();
          this.showMsg = true;
          // this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          console.log('Successfully updated!');
        },
        err => {
          this.showErrMsg = true;
          console.log('Update failed!');
        });
    }
  }
}
```

> ```
> ng:///AppModule/UpdateProjectComponent.ngfactory.js:94 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
>     at UpdateProjectComponent.updateProject (:4200/main.js:2678)
>     at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/UpdateProjectComponent.ngfactory.js:111)
>     at handleEvent (:4200/vendor.js:101276)
>     at callWithDebugContext (:4200/vendor.js:102894)
>     at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (:4200/vendor.js:102530)
>     at dispatchEvent (:4200/vendor.js:88996)
>     at :4200/vendor.js:90893
>     at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (:4200/vendor.js:94272)
>     at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (:4200/vendor.js:193518)
>     at SafeSubscriber.next (:4200/vendor.js:193457)
> ```

If I deleted 'name' field showed the same problem with description....
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you have a ````ng-app="dateInputExample"```` in your html? That is AngularJS syntax for bootstrapping your application. In Angular, you bootstrap your application in ````AppModule````.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason for Error :**

`[(ngModel)]="projectData.name"` , if you are using `[(ngModel)]` 2-way data binding it will need some initial values, but it gets undefined

**1st Solution `*ngIf='projectData'`:**

```
<div class="container custom-container">
    <form [formGroup]="updateProjectForm" (ngSubmit)="updateProject(updateProjectForm.value)" class="ui form"
        style="margin-left: 3%; width: 30%;">
        <h1 id="projectTitle">Update Project</h1>

        <div style="margin: 0 auto;" *ngIf='projectData'>     <!-- HERE -->
            <div style="margin-top: 100px;">
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Project Name</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="projectName" class="form-control" name="projectName"
                        [(ngModel)]="projectData.name" placeholder="Your project name"
                        [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : submitted && updateProjectForm.controls.projectName.errors}" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && updateProjectForm.controls.projectName.errors" class="err_msg form-text">
                        <p class="err-msg">Project Name is required</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**2nd Soltuion (Provide some initial value):**

```
project: Project = {
    ..., // other values too
    name : ''
};
```

**3rd option, remove `[(ngModel)]` 2-way data binding from all:**

```
this.project.name = projectDataFromForm.projectName;
this.project.description = projectDataFromForm.projectDescription;
this.project.expiryDate = projectDataFromForm.expiryDate;
this.project.budget = projectDataFromForm.budget;
// this.project.projectTypeId = this.idprojecttype;
this.project.projectTypeId = this.prMultiselectComponent.getSelectedItems();
this.project.skills = this.skillMultiselectComponent.getSelectedItems();

// --- Patch value will set values in your form ---
this.updateProjectForm.patchValue(this.project); // <---- HERE
```

Comment: I used 1st your and 3rd solutions and it helped  and initialized project:
Project = new Project; But i don't understand what do this.updateProjectForm.patchValue(this.project);

Comment: @DenisDeniben, it will set the values in your inputs without `[(ngModel)]` and you can get values on submitting with `this.updateProjectForm.value`

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is caused by this line:

```js
this.project.name = projectDataFromForm.projectName;
```

because as far as I can see, you don't instantiate your `Project` object.

In `ngOnInit`, try adding

```js
this.project = new Project(/* include any necessary data here for the Project constructor */);
```